# Do We Need/Want More Moderators for WPSE?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

First: this question is about *supporting* our current mods, not to criticize them. I think they do a fantastic job.

But, as they themselves have said: they are over-worked, to the point of officially asking for a break from moderator duties. While we can do many things to ensure that we community members are doing our part to police and to improve our site, there is only so much that non-moderators can do.

So: do we want to ask to have *more* moderators, so that our mods have some additional, *real* help?

If so: how many would be a good number? (One idea: just take the last election slate, and for any of that slate who still want to be moderators, just make it so.)

Comment: Note that moderators do not have to *ask* for a break from moderator duties.  They can ease up or stop for a while if they wish.  It's considered *common courtesy* for them to inform SE if they have capacity issues or are burnt out and not going to focus on moderator duties for a while.

Comment: The three of us discussed it offline before bringing it back to the community.  I wanted to make sure we were all on the same page.  I, personally, feel comfortable moving forward but suggested we add some more members to the team while the other mods take a bit of a break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have already decided that you'll be conducting an election in the coming weeks. There will be an announcement banner on the main page about it, and we'll determine the number of new mods that will be elected.

We evaluate election-readiness yearly. In WordPress.SE's case, the moderators requesting a break from their duties sped up that process, though only by about a month.

Comment: Is that *we* the **Community Team**, or *we* the **WPSE community** who will decide the number of moderators? (Also: **hi**, welcome, and thanks for popping in!)

Comment: We-the-Community Team. :D You're all free to tell us how many you feel like you ought to have, of course, but Community Team ultimately makes the decision. And, hello, how do you do. :D